# How to set global webhooks for rundeck jobs?

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way of setting a global webhook for the various states of the jobs: onStart, onSuccess, onFailure.

I would like all data for the jobs to go to a single URL where I can do whatever I need.  Currently, it seems I have to set it for each job, and each state.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not available in Rundeck as of 3.0.23 (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/n_Cviw3N4K8/453fICitDQAJ).  It is apparently roadmapped for the future.